# Surjectivity of restriction map between $H^2$

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ and $H$ be two profinite groups such that $H$ is open distinguished with $G/H$ cyclique of some order $m \equiv 0 \text{ (mod }p \text{)}$. Do we know some conditions on $G$ and $H$ such that the restriction map
$$H^2(G, \mathbf{F}_p) \rightarrow H^2(H, \mathbf{F}_p)^{G/H}$$
is surjective ? (with trivial action of $G$ on $\mathbf{F}_p$). Or more generally do we know something "explicit" (meaning computable in the case I'm interested in, e.g. for galois groups with ramification conditions) about its kernel and cokernel ?

(I asked this question on StackExchange, maybe it will have more success here.)

Comment: The image is precisely the kernel of differential $H^2(H,\mathbb{F}_p)^{G/H}\to H^2(G/H,H^1(H,\mathbb{F}_p))$ from the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.

Comment: Can you define this map explicitely at the level of cocycles?

Comment: Sure, just unwind the definition of this spectral sequence -- to write down spectral sequence you need to choose resolutions for certain $H$- and $G/H$-modules. So, choose bar resolutions -- the first page of the spectral sequence will be made of usual group cohomology complexes.

Comment: It seems to me that the image is $\textit{contained}$ in the kernel of differential, but not equal in general since the $E_{\infty}^{0,2}$ term of the spectral sequence is only a submodule of $Ker(H^2(H,\mathbb{F}_p)^{G/H}\to H^2(G/H,H^1(H,\mathbb{F}_p)))$. Am I wrong ? (I'm not used to spectral sequences...)

Comment: Yes, you are right, my first statement is wrong. We should take the kernel of differential $ker(H^2(H,\mathbb{F}_p)^{G/H}\to H^2(G/H,H^1(H,\mathbb{F}_p)))\to E_3^{3,0}$. All higher differentials are zero by dimension reasons.